# Displaying properties of GeoJSON in popup on Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, features, popup

This is my simple GeoJSON with Leaflet map.  I want to display properties as popup but I don't know why it is empty.

Can you tell me my mistake?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A Leaflet map!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
<style>
#map {
width: 960px;
height: 500px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script>
    var map = L.map('map',{
    center: [49.833352, 18.163662],
    zoom: 10
    });
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    var data ={
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              23.4850463378073,
              46.7440954850672
            ]
          },
          "properties": {
            "f1": 11793,
            "f2": "BT"
          }
        }
      ]
    };

var layer = L.geoJson(data, {
}).addTo(map);
layer.bindPopup('<h1>'+feature.properties.f1+'</h1><p>name: '+feature.properties.f2+'</p>');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 30):

The line where you create and bind your popup should have been included in the [`onEachFeature`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#geojson-oneachfeature) option of your `L.geoJSON` factory.

```js
var layerGroup = L.geoJSON(data, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup('<h1>'+feature.properties.f1+'</h1><p>name: '+feature.properties.f2+'</p>');
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Demo: http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/wuseg/1/edit?html,output

Having this line outside the factory makes it access your outer scope `layer` variable, which is actually the GeoJSON Layer Group that holds *all* the features from your GeoJSON data, therefore it tries to bind a popup on each of these features (in your case, there is only 1 marker, but it could be more).

Above all, it does not know any `feature` variable, which creates an error.

Answer (score 11):

Build a simple popup content for any properties in a simple way, in one line:

```
var layer = L.geoJSON(data, {
 onEachFeature: function (f, l) {
   l.bindPopup('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(f.properties,null,' ').replace(/[\{\}"]/g,'')+'</pre>');
 }
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use below codes:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    // does this feature have a property named popupContent?
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.Name && feature.properties.Lat && feature.properties.Lon) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Name+"("+feature.properties.Lat+","+feature.properties.Lon+")",);
    }
}
/// for Show in map marker style and popup
    L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
    }, 
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature

}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: How come this answer is also published as a question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354704/openpopup-in-geojson-data-in-leaflet ?

Comment: I have done this part. my attribute value is now showing on click basis. But now I want to use this as label. This is why I have asked the question. I am finding it hard to make label of geojson data in leaflet.