# Leaflet markers from CSV with multiple columns employing omnivore

Tags: leaflet, geojson, csv, parse

Goal: Show markers for lat-lon positions from a CSV file. The other columns need to be placed in pop-up as attributes.

CSV file can be seen at: [airport.csv](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/markers-from-csv/)

Code:

```
headers = ['iata', 'title', 'city', 'state', 'country'] // determined programmatically and excludes latitude longitude

customLayerLocalData = L.geoJson(null, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        var popupContent = '';
        $.each(headers, function (h) {
            popupContent += feature.properties + '.' + headers[h];
            if (h != headers.length - 1) {
                popupContent += '+'
            };

        });
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    },
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, customMarkerOptions);
    }
});
layerLocalData = omnivore.csv.parse(fr.result, null, customLayerLocalData).addTo(map);
```

Problem: The pop-up shows the object:

```
 [object Object].iata
+[object Object].title
+[object Object].city
+[object Object].state
+[object Object].country
```

If I change: `layer.bindPopup(popup content);` to `layer.bindPopup(eval(popup content));`, it works. But, I am not happy with this solution (does not feel right). Morever, in this case new lines can't be inserted inside the custom geoJSON layer.

I'm looking for a smarter solution that can interpret the 'popupContent' and pass onto to `layer.bindPopup` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a javascript problem regarding [object property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

So when you're doing this...

```
 popupContent += feature.properties + '.' + headers[h];
```

What you want is to access e.g. `feature.properties.iata` when `headers[h]` has the value `"iata"`. And it's failing, because the code is doing string concatenation instead.

The approach here is to read and re-read how [object property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) work, and then

```
 popupContent += feature.properties[ headers[h] ];
```

As a bonus, you can get rid of the jQuery iterators and the manual concatenation of `"+"` by levaraging [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/map) and [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/join), e.g.:

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    var popupContent = headers.map(function (header){
        return feature.properties[header];
    }).join('+');

    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
},
```

Comment: This is an expert, to-the-point, answer and very much appreciated. I ended up with: 

`var popupContent = headers.map(function (header) {return header + ':' + feature.properties[header];}).join('<br>');`

The other approach from my prev link below also worked, but I prefer this .map:
`l.bindPopup('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(f.properties, null, ' ').replace(/[\{\}"]/g, '') + '</pre>'`. Unsure why someone gave it -1, but that was also okay.

Answer (score -1):

It was tricky a bit but someone savvy has answered it in a different context here:

[Displaying properties of GeoJSON in popup on Leaflet?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229723/displaying-properties-of-geojson-in-popup-on-leaflet/229743)

I am not closing/deleting this QnA; someone else like me may need it. Thanks.