# .openPopup() in Geojson data in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

Why `.openPopup()` is not working in case of GeoJSON data in Leaflet? I want to use this as labeling in my map.

```
    ////////////// for Popup label
 function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    // does this feature have a property named popupContent?
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.Name && feature.properties.Lat && feature.properties.Lon) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Name+"("+feature.properties.Lat+","+feature.properties.Lon+")");
    }
}
/// for Show in map marker style and popup
    L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
    }, 
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature

}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser console? There seems to be one comma too much at the end of `.bindPopup` input parameter.

Comment: my mistake. I need to label my attribute value instead of on click open. my input data is geojson file. Do you have any solution? thanks

Comment: You are not calling `.openPopup` after binding popup to layer. It should be `layer.bindPopup( ... ).openPopup();`

Comment: Thanks. But Still not working. This technique works with marker but doesn't work with  GeoJSON data.

Comment: Yes problem solved. Thanks a lot